# SVG circle has a gap

Tags: css, svg, geometry

I am trying to build a pie chart using SVG and some trickery.

```css
.pie {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.pie .background {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eaeaea;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
}
.pie .chart {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #f73319;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  animation: 2s linear slice;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
@keyframes slice {
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 75 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
  <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
  <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw2c1rss/1/).

The code is quite simple: I am using `stroke-dasharray` to have a dash that covers the whole circle and can be adjusted to make a slice. However, for some reason none of the browsers “close” the circle.

If you want to adjust the pie chart `%`, you can change the first number in

```
stroke-dasharray: 75 100;
```

The second number specifies the gap between different dashes. The reason it is at `100` is because it is equal to the radius of the circle which is:

```
  radius * width * 2 * pi
=   0.25 *    64 * 2 * pi
= 100.53
```

Comment: That is what make the whole pie chart thing work. without it, it is just a circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circle is r="25%" in a viewBox="0 0 64 64" that means it has a radius of 16 (25% of 64)

The circumference of a circle is 2 * PI * r which for r=16 is 100.53 i.e. slightly larger than 100 so the first dasharray value of 100 does not complete the circle. Just make the first value 100.53 and it will draw all the way round.

```css
.pie{
            border-radius:50%;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        .pie .background{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#eaeaea;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:100.53 100;
           
        }
         .pie .chart{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#f73319;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:0 100;
            animation: 2s linear slice ;
            animation-fill-mode:forwards
        }
        @keyframes slice{
            to{stroke-dasharray:100.53 100;}
        }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
    <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
       <circle class="chart" r="16" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried 100.53, I also tried 101 without success. Any trick or workaround that you're aware off?

Comment: I just tried again and not for me: https://jsfiddle.net/pw2c1rss/2/. Could you share a code example?

Comment: I've added code that works (at least it does on Firefox) to my answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks, It is the first value that should be changed. Thanks for your help :)