# piechart using svg and react

Tags: svg, pie-chart

I created a pie chart in React using the svg pattern from this tutorial https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/

With four pieces I have

For all four pieces:
`stroke-dasharray: 25, 100;`

For each piece I also have: 
`stroke-dashoffset: 0;`,
`stroke-dashoffset: -25;`,
`stroke-dashoffset: -50;` and
`stroke-dashoffset: -75;`

Problem is I get a gap between the first and the last piece so the pieces does not fully fill the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out the answer by looking at this similar thread [SVG circle has a gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111365/svg-circle-has-a-gap?rq=1)

It turned out I had a radius of 16 the full circle was more than 100%. Setting `stroke-dasharray: 100,53`and dividing my radius by 1.0053 helped.